# Conversion coordinates to decimal degrees in Python

Tags: python, coordinate-system, coordinates, geometry-conversion

I have a pandas DataFrame with coordinates (Longitude and Latitude) in the following format: (005304000W, 384035000N). I need to convert those coordinates to what I believe are decimal degrees (e.g. -0.209383, 40.276665). I assume WGS84.

How can I do it with a Python library? I'm a bit confused about the format of my input coordinates. Is it 00º53'04''W and 38º40'35''N?

Here is a reproducible example to work with:

```
import pandas as pd

# Example data
id = {'Id': ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]}
lon = {'Longitude': ["005304000W", "004622000W", "001522000W", "000023000E", "000457000E"]}
lat = {'Latitude': ["384035000N", "384045000N", "383140000N", "384906000N", "384733000N"]}
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(id), pd.DataFrame(lon), pd.DataFrame(lat)], axis=1)
df.head()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to get lon and lat as dictionaries then all you have to do is extract out the lists of coordinates from your Python dictionaries.  The list items are strings so you can slice the strings and convert them to integers.  Then do the math to get decimal degrees.

```
lon = {'Longitude': ["005304000W", "004622000W", "001522000W", "000023000E", "000457000E"]}
lat = {'Latitude': ["384035000N", "384045000N", "383140000N", "384906000N", "384733000N"]}
#get the latitudes and longitudes as a list....
longitudes = lon['Longitude']
latitudes = lat['Latitude']
#iterate both lists at the same time using the built-in zip function
for (longs, lats)  in zip(longitudes, latitudes):
    #slice up the lists getting the pieces that you want.  The items are text so convert to integers at the same time
    longdd = int(longs[0:2])
    longmm = int(longs[2:4])
    longsec= int(longs[4:-1])/1000
    hemi= longs[-1:]
    if hemi =='W':
        scaler = -1
    else:
        scaler = 1
    print('longitude ', scaler * (longdd+ longmm/60 + longsec/3600))

    latdd = int(lats[0:2])
    latmm = int(lats[2:4])
    latsec= int(lats[4:-1])/1000
    hemi= lats[-1:]
    if hemi =='S':
        scaler = -1
    else:
        scaler = 1    
    print('latitude ', scaler * (latdd+ latmm/60 + latsec/3600))
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this and it works, but there is a small difference between the conversion your method performs and the conversion when inserting the coordinates in Google Maps. For example, for the 5th point (38°47'45.6 "N 0°04'01.2 "E) I get (38.792500, 0.082500) with your method and (38.796000, 0.067000) with Google Maps.

Comment: That is because you have inserted a decimal value for the seconds where I am assuming the seconds value returned by your list is an integer. I have your values as DDMMSSSSS but you are saying they should be DDMMSS.SSS?

Comment: @GBG Looks like there's a small bug in your code where you are using `longmm` and `latmm` twice rather than using the seconds values.

Comment: You don't assign sign from the hemisphere, so all values are north and east

Comment: Thanks Mintx.  I have corrected the code, thanks for catching that.  Yes, Vince, I left the north and east coding to sermomon so as not to over compliment the solution (as detailed in the original posts comments).  I have updated my answer to include the hemisphere values.  @sermomon, I am assuming your seconds values are in SS.SSS and as such I divide by 1000.

Comment: @GBG thank you very much for the corrections. I have checked some points on an orthophoto and indeed it is coded as SS.SSS.